# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer will not stop nor shutdown

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I programmatically create, start, stop, and shutdown a Spring `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` in my application as part of a more important service that manages it's lifecycle.

I also register these DMLC's as MBeans, so I can manage them from JConsole.

I am unable to "shutdown" my DMLC and it appears it is because there is always an "active" invoker listener that will not go away after I stop the DMLC.  *I understand the 'receiveTimeout = -1' issue and mine is 5 seconds (5000 ms).  So, that is not the problem.*

I've attached a screen shot of my JConsole DLMC attributes *after* "stop" operation is invoked.  You can see Running = false, but "ActiveConsumerCount = 1".  So, shutdown() operation will hang and never completely shutdown my container.  How do I completely stop & shutdown a DMLC programmatically?

Spring version is 4.1.5
ActiveMQ 5.10.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem with a `receiveTimeout` of 5000. I suggest you turn on trace-level debugging - you should see the thread logging every 5 seconds. If not, it is likely the thread is stuck somewhere upstream (in the listener).

Take a thread dump (e.g. with jstack) to confirm.